# how to find the unique items in a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list,

```
 mylist=[4, 4, 2, 1, 2]

 my expected output is =[1]
```

I tried `list(set(mylist))` but its not helping

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may use [**`collections.Counter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the count of all the items present in the list, then filter it using *list comprehension* the items having count as `1`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> mylist=[4, 4, 2, 1, 2]
>>> [k for k, v in Counter(mylist).items() if v==1]
[1]
```